# mysql INSERT INTO loop not inserting some rows

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I have a loop that is inserting new rows into my database. It is specifically designed to insert a specific number of rows with a unique value in the `'name'` column.

```php
while($rows_inserted < 100) {
    // Create a random number  
      
    //Min & Max values for the random numbers
    $min = 5001;
    $max = 5100;
    
    $number = rand($min,$max);
    
    //Connect to the DB using $con details & execute query
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO cmssps_card_codes (id, parent_id, name, status) VALUES ('', '', '$number', '0')");
    
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) === 1) {
        $rows_inserted++;  // update the counter
    }
}
```

In this particular limited instance, I'm creating 100 "random" numbers between 5001 and 5100 so it's redundant in this instance but the random number is used in production instances - just to avoid confusion.

My problem is that this statement executes successfully, however only 87 odd rows are actually created. I then try running the code to insert a single instance of the previously excluded rows and it enters an endless loop - I can, however, create the row directly in the database. It's as if the PHP code recognises that the row has been created when in fact it hasn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: `name` has a `unique` constraint on it?

Comment: You'll have to show us the table definition, to see if there is some constraint you're trying to violate. Expect to have some duplicate $number's in there.

Comment: if you generate 100 random numbers in an interval of 100 (e.g. 1 .. 100), you are unlikely to get 100 unique numbers! There will be duplicates. That is why you get 87 rows from 100 random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define `$rows_inserted` before the while.

```
 $rows_inserted = 0;
 while($rows_inserted < 100) {
 ....
```

You are inserting 100 rows with 100 different `$number`, so you have to make sure that random can repeat some values example `5012`, `5060`, `5012` ..., if your column `name` has a unique constraint in it that it will not save the duplicate numbers.

You had 87 values saved means you got 13 duplicated not saved. So either:

**1-**  get unique `$number` like that

```
$number = 5001 + $rows_inserted ;
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO cmssps_card_codes (id, parent_id, name, status) 
                   VALUES ('', '', '$number', '0')");
```

**2-** or change your column name and remove the `UNIQUE` constraint there to accept duplicate values.

Comment: Thanks. This seemed to do the trick. It was as others have said too, an issue with duplicates being created and then just skipped.